# HTTP(S) based file server

Tags: software-recommendation, ftp, webserver

I've got a server running Ubuntu 10.04. I've already gotten openssh for ssh and sftp on it.

I've been looking for a web-based (http, or preferably https) file server, perhaps a web-front-end to an (S)FTP server, that allows access to a specific folder, and also allows uploads. It requires user authentication, preferably using PAM.

This web-based solution is for users that are not allowed to use FTP software / browser extension and don't have flash / java browser plugins within their corporate environments.

So far I have looked into:

- Webmin: Includes a file manager, however it uses Java, and I'm looking for a plugin-free implementation.
- Apache2: I was able to set up https and PAM authentication, but the barebone implementation doesn't include file upload (as far as I'm aware of).
- HFS: Haven't tried it out because it is for Windows/wine only, and I don't want to run it under wine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have kept on researching, and found 4 good web-ftp implementations:

- [AjaXplorer](http://ajaxplorer.info/) using following config: [FTP](http://ajaxplorer.info/plugins/auth/ftp/)
- [net2ftp](http://www.net2ftp.com)
- [Web-FTP](http://www.web-ftp.org/)
- [phpWebFTP](http://www.phpwebftp.com/)

All work great with apache2 (with https), and proftpd (used for it's great PAM integration and ease of use). However the last two are a bit old and their designs are not the prettiest. and net2ftp has a huge banner with its name as well as a "complicated" login screen, with many options that a simple user doesn't need. That's why I'm currently using AjaXplorer.

If perhaps anyone else got great web-ftp scripts for apache2, please recommend them!

Comment: A lot of these clients are now stale, but there's still huge demand for web-based FTP. Have a look at Monsta FTP. It's an FTP/SFTP web-based client and code editor. It's free to download from https://www.monstaftp.com (disclaimer: I'm involved with this project)

Answer (score 1):

If you need read/write, it sounds like you're looking for Apache (or [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpDavModule)) and Webdav. If you only need read-access, you can just serve directory listings from the webserver itself.

- http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/WebDAV

Comment: Thank you for your response. As far as I can see, WebDAV requires using standalone clients or browser extensions to connect properly, i.e. to have full upload capability.

Comment: Most OSes have built-in support for connecting to read/write DAV shares.

Comment: @Michael I know that Nautilus, Windows Explorer and OSX's Finder can all connect to webdav shares, out of the box.

Comment: @Oli and Jeremy Kerr: Thanks for the responses! I'm not sure whether it is possible to access WebDAV behind a corporate firewall. Thus far I've had a Web-ftp server on Windows, accessible easily from every browser, and I don't want to overwhelm the end-user with something new. And every firewall allows ports 80 and 443.

Comment: @Michael Webdav uses HTTP over port 80. It's by far the most firewall-friendly file-transfer protocol there is.

Comment: @Oli: Oh! Ok, my bad. I will have another look at it then! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I Just found this also, it looks very promising...

http://ubuntuguide.net/http-server-support-uploading-files-from-windows-in-ubuntu